# count the number of rows if its pass the like method mysql

Tags: mysql, database, count, statistics

i'd like to count the number of rows if its pass the like syntax. I ve got a column wich have 3 different variable A,N or both AN. And i want to sum if its A or N or both. And i need it for each company

i'll tried the following line:

```
select szallito_nev, extract(month from beerkezes_datuma) as het, count(if(intezkedes = '%n%',1,0))as 'N' from temporary GROUP BY szallito_nev,extract(month from beerkezes_datuma);
```

but it gives me to many pieces of the items.

the main table

```
DUPAREC PAPÍRGYŰJTŐ ÉS FELD. KFT    |2013-11-11 15:42:19 |  Á
HAMBURGER RECYCLING ADRIA D.O.O.    |2013-11-11 16:57:01 |  N
HAMBURGER RECYCLING POLSKA          |2013-11-11 17:09:36 |  N
KALO-MÉH TR. KFT                    |2013-11-11 17:26:1  |  N
HAMBURGER RECYCLING POLSKA          |2013-11-11 17:50:28 |  N
DUPAREC PAPÍRGYŰJTŐ ÉS FELD. KFT    |2013-11-11 15:28:00 |  Á
```

and what i want

```
company                         |month|number of N
A.K.S.D. VÁROSGAZDÁLKODÁSI KFT  |11  |4
AVE TATABÁNYA ZRT               |11  |0
B.P. SELECTIVE 2001 KFT         |11  |2
BÜCHL HUNGÁRIA KFT              |11  |1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the % wildcard character with the = comparison operator.

```
count(if(intezkedes = '%n%',1,0))
```

should be either

```
count(if(intezkedes LIKE '%n%',1,0))
```

or, since you are trying to match a single character, even better

```
count(if(intezkedes = 'N',1,0))
```

Comment: still given false result

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the problem was with the count() method i changed it into sum()and now it works fine

select szallito_nev, extract(month from beerkezes_datuma) as honap, sum(if(intezkedes like '%n%',1,0))as 'N' from temporary GROUP BY szallito_nev,extract(month from beerkezes_datuma);